# Should I use causal inference for this usecase?

Tags: causality

I have a historical dataset of several million sales, and some of them are marked as returned. I have multiple variables, such as product, customers, creation date, etc. My goal is to determine the cause of the returned orders, such as whether it's a combination of a particular product type with a specific customer.

- I have analyzed my dataset using multiple dimensions for example estimating the percentage of returns by customer and by product type, it gave me some insights but with all these dimensions I couldn't really find a combination of variables that causes the returns.
- I have also tried to build a tress based model to try and predict whether the order is a return or not, then plotting the feature importance but it isn't enough.

So, I'd like to know if it will be appropriate to use causal inference? I've seen several packages, such as EconML and CausalML, but I am unsure what intervention would be suitable in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: Asking whether or not apply Causal inference will miss a important points here. What are your scientific question ? What are you trying to assess ? What will be your estimate ? Before going any further, clarify theses questions. Then you will decide what to do.

Comment: @MangnierLoïc I've edited my question and added some info, thanks!

Comment: Traditional CI is definitely focused more on the effects of causes, whereas you are more interested in the causes of effects since you don't have a particular intervention here. I think the area you might be looking for is causal discovery.